# Is "I need to deposit my checks" correct?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrase-requests

I haves a few checks and I want put them into my bank account.

1. What's the approriate and natural sentence to describe my intention at a counter?
2. Is "I need to deposit my checks" correct?
3. What is "chashing a check"?

Comment: This is really three unrelated questions in one. StackExchange works best when you post one question per question. Moreover, the first question is not constructive (there are a number of possible answers, all equally correct), the third one quite obviously contains a typo upon whose removal the meaning is self-explanatory or at least can be looked up in a dictionary of your choice, and all three questions are a better fit for our sister site specifically for [English language learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "I need to deposit my checks" sounds okay, but often you will also hear "I need to make a deposit." Alternatively, people will say "some" instead of "my," as in "I need to deposit some checks."
2. Yes, it's perfectly fine.
3. I think you mean "cashing a check." This means that the teller at the counter will give you (in cash) the amount of money specified on the check.

Comment: In BrE, while "deposit" is perfectly acceptable bank-speak, normal usage is "pay in". "I need to make a deposit" might get you directed to a public convenience.